# How to Compute a nonzero point $v= \langle v_x, v_y \rangle$ of Nodal Curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, computational-algebra

*This is not homework question. I am writing a research paper and studying the behaviors of complete algebraic curves and I came across this questions and I am interested in it.*

A [nodal function](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Earapura/graph/nodal.html) is well know. Obviously, $p=(1, \sqrt{2})$ is a point on this [curve](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qvlaemi2wq). Assume that $C = \mathcal{V} (f)$ is the variety of the nodal function. Is there a way to find a nonzero vector $v= \langle v_x, v_y \rangle$ such that $f(p + tv) = f(1+ tv_x, \sqrt{2} + tv_y)$ has a double zero at 0? Is it right to say that any nonzero point on the curve is $v_x$ and $v_y$?

Or what is an explicit way to compute $v= \langle v_x, v_y \rangle$?

When I checked online it suggest to me that "double zero" will mean both $f(p+tv)$ and its derivative with respect to $t$ are zero when $t$ is zero. To find the nonzero vector $v=\langle v_x,  v_y\rangle$ what I did was to plug in $p+tv$ into the nodal function $y^2-x^2(x+1)$ but it seems complicated and I got stuck.

$$f(t+tv_x, \sqrt{2} + tv_y) =  (\sqrt{2} + tv_y)^2 - (t+tv_x)^2(t+tv_x +1) =  (tv_y)^2 + 2 tv_y \sqrt{2} - (tv_x)^3 -4 (tx)^2 - 5tv_x $$

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do here. Can you explain what your underlying goal is?

Comment: Actually, I want to draw the line $p+tv$ and the Nordal curve on the same graph on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qvlaemi2wq). But $p+tv$ can be obtain by finding a nonzero vector $v = \langle x_x, v_y\rangle$ such that $f(p + tv) = f(1+ tv_x, \sqrt{2} + tv_y)$ has a double zero at 0. Is this clear now?

Comment: No, it's still as opaque as before - you haven't defined $p$, what's $(1,\sqrt{2})$ doing here, what picture do you want, etc. Are you trying to construct a rational parametrization of the nodal cubic? I kind of doubt it, since that's already covered in the first link, but that's all I can piece together.

Comment: Oh, you're trying to find the intersection of the tangent line at $p$ with the curve but in a convoluted way. (You can also just plug in to the equation and express things as a polynomial in $t$ - this should be pretty straightforward.) Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and improve your post by making it clearer, adding motivation, showing where you're stuck, etc.

Comment: I will not be responding further until you improve your question with an [edit] as per my last comment. Please focus especially on the *motivation* aspect.

Comment: I've edited the question. Thank you very much!

Comment: You've completely ignored why you want to do this. How did you come to this problem? Is it from a school assignment? A simulation you're running to predict something else? Why do you care about solving this problem? I'm grateful you've added some more details to the post, but I still have *no idea* what your underlying motivations are despite asking several times.

Comment: No this is not a homework question. I am writing a research paper and studying the behaviors of complete algebraic curves and I came across this questions and I am interested it.